# Debian segfault in libc2.7

Tags: linux, debian, segmentation-fault

I am running a test on my machine in which I assigned a lot of IPs to some tap interfaces (created by me before the test) on my debian machine and tried to run curl commands with the source being these IPs. I get lots of seg faults similar to the following:

```
kernel: [14390.470990] curl[25526]: segfault at bf150ff0 ip b76aee93 sp bf150fd4 error 6 in libc-2.7.so[b75c4000+138000]
```

I even get segfaults while trying to do ssh to the machine, trying to create a file, and for a bunch of other commands. This is a Debian Lenny machine. I came across [this debian bug report](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/linux.debian.bugs.dist/9rlEKyhwL2k/hQxdmYOQkpQJ) which concerns the same issue. It says that a workaround is to remove the "unstable" entry from sources.list. I don't haven't pointed it to unstable ever since the beginning. Could someone with more expertise in linux go through the link I gave and explain to me what is going on and what I should do to resolve this?

Comment: see here also http://lists.debian.org/deity/2011/05/msg00048.html